# filter json using jq and get entire other value

Tags: bash, jq

I'm trying to filter the following json object to get the id which doesn't have a domain value which is either "moderator" or "owner" using jq in bash script.The problem is my third domain value is random and not predetermined. How do I filter it?

```
{
 "data":[
   {
      "id":1,
      "domain":"moderator"
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "domain":"owner"
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "domain":"34b5756175a848f7a1395e1a19e10602"
   }
 ]
}
```

Comment: done removed that part, checking for the other two should be enough

Answer (score 1):

You can get just the elements of the array with a different domain via:

```sh
$ jq '.data[] | select(.domain != "moderator" and .domain != "owner")' input.json
{
  "id": 3,
  "domain": "34b5756175a848f7a1395e1a19e10602"
}
```

If you just want the id value and not the entire object, add `| .id` to the end of the `jq` filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `jq` function `select`

```
cat text.json | jq '.data[] | select((.domain != "moderator") and (.domain != "owner"))'
```

Also, you can use the `length` function to get the size of the array.

```
jq '.[] | length' test.json
```